# Can I downgrade from the Windows 8.1 preview to Windows 8 if I have an OEM CD?

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, windows-8-preview, downgrade

The internet is full of vague information about how you can downgrade the Windows 8.1 preview to Windows 8, and I kind of want to try it, but only if it's not going to be too inconvenient to uninstall if I need to.

Here is my exact situation: I installed Windows 8 using an OEM CD. If I install the Windows 8.1 preview, can I use the factory restore feature to downgrade back to Windows 8? Does this change based on whether I installed using the Windows Store or the .iso?

Comment: The upgrade to Windows 8.1 Preview is more or less a one way trip.  The preview installation does not change the factory image.  Why don't you just wait till the final version?  If you install the preview you will have to reinstall all your applications once the final version of Windows 8.1 is released

Comment: To clarify, I don't have a factory image. I built the computer, so it didn't come with Windows 8. I just installed it using an OEM CD.

Comment: You have the ability to create one though.  There is also the refresh image and the option of just reinstalling you applications when the RTM is released.

Answer (score 1):

If you take Windows 7 betas and what some people have reported about Win 8.1 preview, installing a beta copy is a dead-end street.  No way to update to a full version once it is out, and no way to roll it back - a full reinstall needed.  That's why there is the strong language about not using it on a production system.